# Showing sort (order) values on axis

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

The graph below has its member (on the left) sorted by the percentage of blue on the total, which is a measure.

The total value is shown at the bottom, but I would like to show the percentage at the top, ie, the value of the measure used to sort.

[image]

Comment: we need a bit more info, but you can use measure in the tooltip definition-> Balloon Text , e.g. 'The sales is [[Amount]]'

Comment: @ic3 Thanks ! Looking at the tooltip definition got me to find about the value axis configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I

- switched the measures from columns to measures in the cube section of the widget
- edit the value axis configuration and edited the general settings. (notably position right)

[image]

With the following result: (colors and orientation changed). One can see the values properly showing on the right hand side.

[image]